# Is there a proper way to use useNavigation() hook with useEffect() dependencies?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-hooks

I'm trying to interact with react-navigation using useNavigation() hook in response to a callback I'm registering in useEffect(). The linter is warning me that useEffect() has a missing dependency. If I add the navigation hook as a dependency, the effect continuously runs. I'm trying to avoid this and wondering if there is a correct way other than ignoring the linter error.

Providing no dependency array results in the same behavior where the effect continuously fires.

This may be an underlying issue with how the useNavigation() hook from react-navigation-hooks package works.

```js
function MyComponent() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    useEffect(() => {
        navigation.navigate('Home');
    }, []);
}
```

Results in:

`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'navigation'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just an opinionated guess: It's more a question regarding your "architecture".

For example: Wouldn't it make more sense for the custom `useNavigation` hook to return a *function* that can be called by the consumer of the hook instead of an object with all it's functionality?

Here is an example:

```tsx
const useNavigation = () => {
  const [routes, setRoutes] = useState(null);
  ...

  const navigate = (destination: string) => {
    console.log("navigated to ", destination);
  };

  return { navigate, routes };
};

function App() {
  const { navigate } = useNavigation();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Parent</h1>
      <button onClick={() => navigate("Home")}>Navigate me!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working Codesandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/usenavigation-95kql

---

If you nevertheless want to keep this "architecture", you could use a `useRef` hook like so:

```tsx
const navigation = useRef(useNavigation());

useEffect(() => {
  navigation.current.navigate("Home");
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is super helpful, can't believe I didn't see that sooner. In regards to useNavigation hook, this was from the package react-navigation-hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error message is clear, you are missing the useEffect dependency:

```js
function MyComponent() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!navigation) return; // <-- this will avoid any undefined or null calls
        navigation.navigate('Home');
    }, [navigation]); // <-- this dependency
}
```

Comment: problem of the author is that since navigate alters the state of navigation object, adding it to the array of dependencies of useEffect would cause a loop of calls to navigate