# How to setParams using useEffect and avoid getting infinty renderings?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-hooks

I'm using `react-navigation` and I have a dynamic header, so I'm using `setParams` and getting it in the title.

```
const MyComponent = ({navigation}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const { setParams, state } = navigation
        const { params = {} } = state
        const { description } = params
        setParams({ headerTitle: description })
    }, [])

    return (...)
}

MyComponent.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: navigation.getParam('headerTitle')
})
```

The problem here is that I only want to `setParams` once (so I use `[]`) but I get a warning (`eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)`) and says that I need to add `navigation` to the dependency array.

If I add `navigation` to the dependency array, it will become a infinty loop.

`setParam` updates => `navigation` call => `setParam` updates => `navigation` and continues...

How can I call `setParam` only once and avoid do it correctly accordingly to react rule of hooks?

Comment: Try to set `setParams` function as dependency for useEffect.

Comment: @Janiis you can't do that, `setParams` is inside `useEffect` scope. To add something to the dependency array, it needs to be in the component scope. It will give you `'setParams' is not defined.`

Comment: Yes, this must be true. Didn't see you destructured `setParams` function from navigation object.

Comment: Ran into the same issue.  Did you find a fix?

Comment: @Jason for now, the only thing that can "fix" it is disable eslint rule. Do you mind giving a upvote so it can reach more people to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Could `useRef` solve this as suggested at the bottom this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56243575/is-there-a-proper-way-to-use-usenavigation-hook-with-useeffect-dependencies#answer-56245870)?

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { state } = navigation;
  const { params = {} } = state;
  const description = useRef(params.description);
  const setParams = useRef(navigation.setParams);

  useEffect(() => {
    setParams.current({ headerTitle: description.current });
  }, [description, setParams]);

  return (...);
}

MyComponent.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: navigation.getParam('headerTitle')
})
```

I've not tested this but it looks like it should work.

For reference here are the [useRef docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

Answer (score 2):

I'm a year late to the party but... as far as I can tell, when `setParams` is called, navigation is updated, and so the component will re-render. If navigation is part of the dependency array, the useEffect will run again too. The trick is to run `setParams` conditionally based on the current nav params. In your case:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const { setParams, state } = navigation
        const { params = {} } = state
        const { description, headerTitle } = params
        if (description !== headerTitle) {
            setParams({ headerTitle: description })
        }
    }, [navigation])
```

It's a little strange though that you're updating nav params with a value that is also a nav param. It seems simpler to just directly use it:

```
MyComponent.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: navigation.getParam('description')
})
```