# React Navigation v5: useEffect() for header screen interaction?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

According to [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons), we should use useLayoutEffect() for header screen interaction.
I want to achieve the same by useEffect() hook, is the following way correct for it?

```
const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            console.log("Header", flag);
          }}
          title="Update count"
        />
      ),
    });
  }, [flag]);
```

Also, using navigation.setOptions() should change the navigation prop, but how useLayoutEffect() with dependecy [navigation] as in [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons), prevent from going into an infinite cycle?

Comment: Where does it say that "using navigation.setOptions() would change the navigation prop"?

Comment: @satya164 Updated question. I want to know why the navigation prop doesn't change and doesn't go into an infinite cycle

Comment: @satya164 Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/57019318/10117360

Answer (score 0):

> Also, using navigation.setOptions() should change the navigation prop

There's no reason that `setOptions` should change the `navigation` prop. The `navigation` object doesn't contain any options, and updating options is not changing anything in the navigation object.